# Getting error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am running NTLM using Spring Security, I am getting the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

How can I resolve this error?

I have the following defined in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Update 1

I resolved that error, now I am getting

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'filterSecurityInterceptor' is defined

and I have the following

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy">
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
    <value>
    CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
    PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
    /**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, exceptionTranslationFilter, ntlmFilter, filterSecurityInterceptor
    </value>
    </property>
    </bean>`
```

---

I changed my applicationContext.xml as follows because like @Sean Patrick Floyd mentioned some elements were old and dead and buried. However I have other errors now which needs to be fixed :-)

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd">
  <!--<authentication-manager alias="_authenticationManager"></authentication-manager>-->
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
      <security:user name="testuser" password="PASSWORD" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
      <security:user name="administrator" password="PASSWORD" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
  <bean id="userDetailsAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.icesoft.icefaces.security.UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider">
    <security:custom-authentication-provider/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="ntlmEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/accessDenied.jspx"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="ntlmFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilter">
    <security:custom-filter position="NTLM_FILTER"/>
    <property name="stripDomain" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultDomain" value="domain"/>
    <property name="netbiosWINS" value="domain"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="_authenticationManager"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="ntlmEntryPoint"/>
  </bean>
  <security:http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
                 entry-point-ref="ntlmEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.jspx" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  </security:http>
  <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false"/>
    <property name="decisionVoters">
      <list>
        <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where did you get this ancient configuration element? The qualified class name is `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy`. `org.acegisecurity` has been dead for years.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#delegating-filter-proxy) docs:

> Notice that the filter is actually a
>   DelegatingFilterProxy, and not the
>   class that will actually implement the
>   logic of the filter. What
>   DelegatingFilterProxy does is **delegate
>   the Filter's methods through to a bean
>   which is obtained from the Spring
>   application context**. This enables the
>   bean to benefit from the Spring web
>   application context lifecycle support
>   and configuration flexibility. **The
>   bean must implement
>   javax.servlet.Filter and it must have
>   the same name as that in the
>   filter-name element**. Read the Javadoc
>   for DelegatingFilterProxy for more
>   information

You need to define a bean named `springSecurityFilterChain` that implements `javax.servlet.Filter` in your application context.

From [Getting Started with Security Namespace Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started):

> If you are familiar with pre-namespace
>   versions of the framework, you can
>   probably already guess roughly what's
>   going on here. **The `<http>` element is
>   responsible for creating a
>   `FilterChainProxy` and the filter beans
>   which it uses**. Common problems like
>   incorrect filter ordering are no
>   longer an issue as the filter
>   positions are predefined.

So you need at least [A Minimal `<http>` Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal)

Comment: See here. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started. The springSecurityFilterChain  is an internal infrastructure bean that is automatically provided by Spring Security.

Comment: @Ritesh you misread the docs. It is automatically created only if you use the `<http>` tag from the mvc namespace

Comment: @Polappan Can you update your question to show what you did to fix the problem to run NTLM with spring security?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in pure Java configuration?

Answer (score 6):

Sean Patrick Floyd is absolutely right but I think it is worth mention one solution, which took to much time for me.

You simply add @ImportResource annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.company"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:security.xml"})
public class CompanyWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <http use-expressions="true">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error"/>
    </http>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java configuration, you can use the following annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

That will import the `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration` configuration class which defines the `springSecurityFilterChain` bean.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide spring security file with minimal configuration

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```