# No bean named authenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named ‘springSecurityFilterChain’ is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090890/getting-error-org-springframework-beans-factory-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-n)

In my Spring Application, I keep getting this error:

```
No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to add a gobal <authentication-manager> element to your configuration (with child <authentication-provider> elements)? Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref attribute on your <http> and <global-method-security> elements.
```

In my Spring Security context xml file, I have defined the following:

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.myProject.core.security.MyUserDetailsService" />

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="com.myProject.core.security.HmacPasswordEncoder" />

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" >
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Any ideas why its complaining, when I have clearly defined my authentication-manager and authentication-provider?

Note: this might help, its a more descriptive error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean
'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2' while setting bean
property 'sourceList' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0'
while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve
reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'
while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0':
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named
'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to
add a gobal <authentication-manager> element to your configuration (with child
<authentication-provider> elements)? Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref
attribute on your <http> and <global-method-security> elements.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The authenticationManager is looked up by name, so just change it to the following:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: or even <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

Comment: just remove the `id="clientAuthenticationManager"` from the second suggestion and see if that works - see updated edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Spring Security Context file to look for the clientAuthenticationManager.  You can add this line to your http setup

```
<http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManger">
```

Comment: Yes it is trying to get authentication manager reference by the name of "authenticationManager", so fill your authentications manager ref.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:

- [Getting error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090890/getting-error-org-springframework-beans-factory-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-n)

> Notice that the filter is actually a DelegatingFilterProxy, and not
>   the class that will actually implement the logic of the filter. What
>   DelegatingFilterProxy does is delegate the Filter's methods through to
>   a bean which is obtained from the Spring application context.
>
> ...
>
> You need to define a bean named springSecurityFilterChain that
>   implements javax.servlet.Filter in your application context.